# Unable to access a specific website using Selenium Webdriver with Ruby on Rails but able to access other websites

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, selenium-webdriver, watir

```
def index
    require 'watir'
    @browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome, headless: true
    @browser.goto "https://vmh.selectlabsoft.com/login"
    @spans = @browser.divs
end
```

If I substitute the vmh link with something trivial like "https://google.com" then I'm able to get a list of divs no problem and see text from the web-page so it boils down to the problem being trying to access vmh.selectlabsoft.com/login.    Any help is much appreciated on how I can solve this.  Also if it helps I'm using Watir but it's based on Selenium-Webdriver.  I'm able to access the vmh website if I just paste the link into a web browser also.

Comment: it works fine for me, what error did you get? This is the output for me.  `"Login\nWelcome to the LIS. Please log in with your initials and password.\nUsername:\nPassword:\n(case sensitive)\nLogin"
"Login\nWelcome to the LIS. Please log in with your initials and password.\nUsername:\nPassword:\n(case sensitive)\nLogin"
"Login\nWelcome to the LIS. Please log in with your initials and password.\nUsername:\nPassword:\n(case sensitive)\nLogin"
""`

Comment: There is no error for me but when I have <%= @spans.length %> on my view it equals 0.  Whether I try to look for divs, spans, h1s, ps it seems to give me nothing.  Could you copy and paste the code you are using; mainly how are you accessing text from the webpage?

Comment: My results are correct? Is that what you want? I simply executed your code and have gotten the output.

Comment: How are you accessing the text of the webpage?  On your view, is it like <% @spans.each do |x| %>  <%= x.text %>  <% end %>.   I also had the wrong link, small change but it's different now.

Comment: I think you are asking something from ruby on rails, I am simply answering what has happened while I executed above comment, it gave me the output I posted there.

Comment: I just added the `Watir gem` and tried this inside a rails index controller method and I get 11 for the length of the `@browser.divs` do you have additional configuration for Watir, perhaps something affecting the time to wait for the page to load?

Comment: Huh, interesting.  Nope it is just as is.  Thank you for the feedback.

Comment: @neydroid Mind if I ask you a few questions about your set up?  I went through the trouble of installing rails on my system instead of developing in the cloud to see if that would fix it but it didn't.  So my few questions, didyou also using 'chromedriver', and what's your OS?

Comment: I tested in Mac OS X with chromedriver installed in headless mode

Comment: does it work the way you expect if you do not use headless mode?

Comment: @titusfortner   That worked!  Thank you very much!  If you would like to create a post I can mark it as correct.

Comment: Hah, well, I asked the question to try to figure out why it wasn't working in headless mode. Technically, I don't think the answer to your question should be just "don't use headless mode." :)